# Unable to increase resolution above 640 x 480. Why?

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I can't find any solution to fix it, and can't change the resolution manually. The color depth is only 16 bit and resolution is 640 x 480. The OS runs fine, but it is difficult to work with such resolution.

Information about my PC configuration:

- Operating system: Windows7 32bit
- Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 1.70GHz
- Display Adapters: Standard VGA Graphics Adapter
- Monitor: AOC1950W

Comment: If possible, could you give us a little more information with regards to your PC specification (hardware etc), and why you can't change your resolution? Is it that you don't know how, or the feature is disabled, or hidden?

Comment: Please gain back control over your question and update it properly. To get further information on how to get control back, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103851/what-should-we-tell-users-with-questions-migrated-and-without-an-account Specifically, head over to [so] and register your account via an OpenID. Then, use the same OpenID and register your [su] account. Once you've done that, you should have regained control over your question and will be able to edit it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a more advanced graphics adapter installed.

If your installed graphics adapter is listed as "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" then you're missing the correct driver for your graphics adapter.

Install the proper driver for your graphics adapter and you will be able to adjust the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the most common answer but open the device manager and remove your graphic driver. Then install it again.